# Extracting numbers from localStorage as numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, type-conversion, local-storage

I store a lot of values in localStorage for an app and needed a way of converting the "string" back into a number - IF it was a number.  The thought being if you force HTML `<input type="number"> on your form, then the data going into the form and extracted from the form IS a number, but once stored - its converted to a string.  So to repopulate that` field later, you must read the localStorage value and convert it back to a number before repopulating the input field - otherwise you start getting a lot of reptitive warnings and sometimes errors because NUMBERS are expected, but localStorage is retrieving strings.

My method:  Assuming the value is inputted as a number, then only a number (digits only) will be stored - thus you can assume only numbers will come out (even if they are a string).  Knowing only numbers will come back allows for this:

```
var allVariables = {} ;
var reg = new RegExp(/^\d+$/) ;  // this accounts for digits only
for (var x=0; x<localStorage.length;x++) {
  var keyValue = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(x)) ;
  if (reg.text(keyValue)) {
    keyValue = parseInt(keyValue) ;
  }
  allVariables[localStorage.key(x)] = keyValue ;
}
```

I even expanded on this to account for true/false booleans...can't use 0/1 easily without get confused with a number.  Another method I have seen is underscoring the key name to identify the typeof for later conversion:

ie:

```
key1_str
key2_boo
key3_int
key4_obj
key5_flo
```

Then identify the "_xxx" to convert that value appropriately.

I am asking to see others approach to this problem or suggestions and recommendations on how to improve it.  Mine is not perfect...though neither is localStorage...but still looking for improvement.s

Comment: save it as JSON

Comment: Not certain that would work either, because the localStorage has saved the number 12345 as "12345".  Importing or saving it as a JSON (without converstion) would still have it as:  `"Key" : "12345"`  versus: `"key" : 12345`

Comment: @rolinger not true...copy my answer to your console and run it

Comment: saved string vill be `'"123"'` and number will be `'123'`. Just parse it back.

Comment: Also look into using `ngStorage` module. It takes care of all setting and getting and parsing as simple as `$localStorage.myData = $scope.data`

Answer (score 10):

suppose you have `"keyName" : "12345"`.
Tricky solution is:

```
var newInt = +localStorage.getItem('keyName')
```

this extra + will convert the string to integer.

Comment: Not all key/values are numbers though, how does + handle a true string?  the above evaluates for number then converts if necessary, otherwise leave it alone.  `var a = "12345abcdef"; var newInt = +a ;`  ???

Comment: I have mentioned an example. This + just converts string to integer if the numbers are formed in string. Use it if you are sure that the value contains just numbers in string form. On your second comment you mentioned a data structure like it.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of storing lots of single keys you might consider storing whole objects to less numbers of storage keys that you stringfiy to json and parse when retrieving. JSON methods will retain type

```
var obj= {
   id:100,
   anotherProp:'foo'
} 

localStorage.setItem('myObj',JSON.stringify(obj));
var newObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObj'));
console.log(typeof newObj.id)//number
```

Comment: Interesting.  I will give that one a try.  the entire object is stored as a string, but within the object various key/values won't have quotes around them, thus on extraction should maintain its data type.

Comment: yes...correct...same for `true` and `false` or `null` which you would also need to convert when storing as string

Comment: also much easier to keep track of what is in your localStorage when you search it manually in dev tools if you use it a lot on same site

Comment: Much cleaner.  A better example that supports stricter Typescript settings is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46915314/2023941

Answer (score 0):

try to convert:

```
function getProbablyNumberFromLocalStorage(key) {
   var val = localStorage.getItem(key);
   return (isNan(+val) || val==null) ? val  : +val;
}
```

Comment: You may need this: " || '{}' "