# Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dotnetcore 20 and angular4 project that I am trying to create a userService and get the user to my home component. The backend works just fine but the service doesn't. The problem is on **localStorage**. The error message that I have is :

> Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>     Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

And my userService

```
import { User } from './../models/users';
import { AppConfig } from './../../app.config';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';



@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor(private http: Http, private config: AppConfig) { }

getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/users', this.jwt()).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}

getById(_id: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/users/' + _id, this.jwt()).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}

create(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + '/users/register', user, this.jwt());
}

update(user: User) {
    return this.http.put(this.config.apiUrl + '/users/' + user.id, user, this.jwt());
}

delete(_id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.config.apiUrl + '/users/' + _id, this.jwt());
}

// private helper methods

private jwt() {
    // create authorization header with jwt token
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token });
        return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }
}
```

And my home.component.ts is

```
import { UserService } from './../services/user.service';
import { User } from './../models/users';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
currentUser: User;
users: User[] = [];

constructor(private userService: UserService) {
   this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.loadAllUsers();
}

deleteUser(_id: string) {
   this.userService.delete(_id).subscribe(() => { this.loadAllUsers() });
}

private loadAllUsers() {
   this.userService.getAll().subscribe(users => { this.users = users; });
}
```

The error is on `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));`

Comment: Don't you have to end a type with a ? to say that it's nullable? I'm not sure where you're specifying the string type.

Comment: In this case, I don't even know which one is null and which one is a string. The error is on localStorage. It just doesn't get the user from localStorage.

Answer (score 431, accepted):

As the error says, `localStorage.getItem()` can return either a string or `null`. `JSON.parse()` requires a string, so you should test the result of `localStorage.getItem()` before you try to use it.

For example:

```
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '{}');
```

or perhaps:

```
const userJson = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
this.currentUser = userJson !== null ? JSON.parse(userJson) : new User();
```

See also the [answer from Willem De Nys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53725236/107660). If you are confident that the `localStorage.getItem()` call can never return `null` you can use the non-null assertion operator to tell typescript that you know what you are doing:

```
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')!);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this answer, it makes sense, yet I tried it here but am still running into that same error, mind a look see? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715260/typescript-json-parse-error-type-null-is-not-assignable-to-type-string

Comment: Actually, sorry the first example you posted works, the 2nd one didn't :) `this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '{}');`

Answer (score 94):

the accepted answer is correct, just wants to add a newer and shorter answer.

```
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')!);
```

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer to reference yours in case people don't look far enough down the page.

Comment: ONLY If you are confident that the value   can NEVER return null you can use the non-null assertion operator to tell typescript that you know what you are doing

Answer (score 32):

Using Angular or TS:-

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') as string);
```

or

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') as any);
```

Answer (score 31):

The non-null assertion operator worked for me very well:

(1). in my case

```
this.currentUserSource.next(null!)
```

(2). in your case

```
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')!);
```

Comment: private restrictedWord(control: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} {
        return control.value.includes('moo') ? {'restrictedWord': 'moo'} : null!
    }
where I was using null then gave me error

Answer (score 1):

Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  
  loacalitems!: string;
  todos!: Todo[];

  constructor() {
    this.loacalitems = localStorage.getItem("todos");
}
```

because `localStorage.getItem()` return `string or null` solve this problem any variable this type error is define variable

```
localitems!: string | null;
```

this variable holds to type values string or null.
**then write logic**

### Short hande if else

```
this.todos = this.localitems !== null ? JSON.parse(this.localitems) : [];
```

### if-else

```
if(this.localitems !== null){
   // item not null code
   this.todos = JSON.parse(this.localitems)
}else{
   // item is null code
   this.todos = []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  localsetItem: string | null;
  constructor() { 
  this.localsetItem=localStorage.getItem("todos")
  if(this.localsetItem == null)
  {
    this.todos  = [];
  }
  else
      {
    this.todos=JSON.parse(this.localsetItem);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private userSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<User | unknown>(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Any ideas for this:

```
export const useStateWithLocalStorage = (defaultValue: string[], key: string) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    const storedValues = localStorage.getItem(key);

    return storedValues !== null ? JSON.parse(storedValues) : defaultValue;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use the Null coalescing operator `??` in this situation:

```
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') ?? '{}');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled a lot making this issue worked in my case by using the above solution but none of them succeeded.
What workied for me is:

```
   const serializableState: string | any = localStorage.getItem('globalState');
    return serializableState !== null || serializableState === undefined ? JSON.parse(serializableState) : undefined;
```

I had to cast my variable to string | any and then checked if the variable is null or undefined before parsing it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as below

```
router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl!);
```

Comment: You should add supporting information to your answers. An explanation of the non nullish assertion used here would be nice!

Comment: ! is a Non-null assertion operator that tell the compiler explicitly that you are sure the type of value is not null or undefined

Answer (score 0):

A few different answers on here recommend the non-null assertion operator `!`, or using `as string`, or (worse) `as any` (shudder) to type-cast the result for `localStorage.getItem(key)`.

It's important to note that in TypeScript - there is no such thing as a "type conversion."  In fact, there is no such thing as a "type" in general.  TypeScript is really just syntactic sugar on top of JavaScript to support some loose compile-time illusory "type"-checking. When tsc is done with your code, all you're left with is plain ol' JavaScript with all the type annotations stripped away. This is why things like `as` and `any` are dangerous - they allow you to accomplish dumb things like:

```js
const x: number = 5;
const y: string = x as any;
console.log(y); // oops - y is not a string, but the TS compiler thinks it is.
```

Constructs like `!` and `as` (and `any` in any sense) are really just instuctions to the TS compiler that state:

> Hey Mr. TypeScript compiler - I realize that you *think* you know some things, but you can take what you *think* you know, and you can vigorously shove it right up your ol' chocolate-whiz-way. Pucker up, buttercup."

Sometimes when the TS compiler complains, it's doing so for a good reason.  We should consider listening instead of resorting to language constructs that effectively turn off the compiler to prevent it from doing what we perceive as "whining."

Relying on things like `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')!)` or `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') as string)` is a rather bold and risky assertion that `currentUser` will always and forever return a string value that's actually parsable JSON to some specific TS interface we expect on the guarantee that our app will start blowing smoke in production if it doesn't. This is a bad assumption to make.

I would greatly encourage folks encountering this scenario to embrace the use of the `unknown` type, use the myriad type-guards available, and please wrap up things prone to unpredictable side-effects like JSON.parse in try...catch error handling such as:

```js
// mock up some storage value and a model interface
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', '{ "userName": "jtest", "displayName": "Joe Test" }');
interface User {
    userName: string;
    displayName?: string;
}


// typeguard to use on whatever unpredictable garbage JSON.parse might return
const isUser = (maybeUser: unknown): maybeUser is User => 
                                     maybeUser instanceof Object
                                     && 'userName' in maybeUser
                                     && typeof maybeUser.userName === 'string';

// get the current user, falling back to 'undefined' if anything blows up
function retrieveCurrentUser(): User | undefined {
    let user: User | undefined;

    try {
        const storageValue = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
        if (typeof storageValue === 'string') {
            const maybeUser: unknown = JSON.parse(storageValue);
            if (isUser(maybeUser)) user = maybeUser;
        }
    }
    catch {
        // some graceful handling of JSON.parse failing here or 
        // otherwise unable to recover the user from local storage.
    }

    return user;
}

console.log(retrieveCurrentUser());
```