# Typescript: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript

When I make any property of an interface optional, and while assigning its member to some other variable like this:

```
interface Person {
  name?: string,
  age?: string,
  gender?: string,
  occupation?: string,
}

function getPerson() {
  let person = <Person>{name:"John"};
  return person;
}

let person: Person = getPerson();
let name1: string = person.name; // <<< Error here
```

I get an error like the following:

```
TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

How do I get around this error?

Comment: You can solve the issue by adding the Nullish coalescing operator `??`,  

```let name1: string = person.name ?? "";```

it returns the right side if the value is null or undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915002/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string)

Comment: Creating an interface instead of defaulting values worked for me.

Answer (score 911):

You can now use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) that is here exactly for your use case.

It tells TypeScript that even though something looks like it could be null, it can trust you that it's not:

```
let name1:string = person.name!; 
//                            ^ note the exclamation mark here
```

Comment: Until ESLint does not restrict usage of *non-null assertion operator* :)

Comment: @GONeale there are many cases where the transpiler can't figure out on its own that a value cannot be null. One example is a value set e.g. by Angular, and Angular has its own way of guaranteeing that the value cannot be null.

Comment: This is terrible advice! Instead, help the compiler figuring it out. Add a check before accessing the property, where you either throw or return if the name is not set.

Comment: Disagree with these last two comments...E.g. I'm conditionally rendering a visual element if the property exists, and attached to that element is a function which uses the property. An extra non-null check for the property inside the function is unnecessary

Comment: @eazy_g sounds like you are doing something wrong, if you properly validate the null previously, you wouldn't have to non-null check.

Comment: This operator is very helpful when loading environment variables. For example my .env file has a value that I can trust will always be there, but using my env variable inside a third party Configuration Object that is expecting a String will always throw this error. In this case, the solution above was perfect.

Comment: If I want to allow string or null then what changes needed ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a terrible advice to me. I already have a catch, check for falsy values, all variables are directly typed and still typescript can't figure it out on its own. I have pressing tasks which need urgent attention now and I'd like to figure out what typescript configuration setting causes it after.

Comment: Just putting an exclamation at the end of the variable worked for me.

Comment: Sometimes code reviewer don't want to see the non-null assertion so , better to follow this . let name1:string = person.name as string; as @Harry has mentioned below.

Comment: I never understood what is it for just memorized it as a magic spell (excuse me);

Comment: It's not true that "if you validate nulls properly" you won't run into this issue. If your validation is not in the same block (i.e. in a separate called function) TS will not see it.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. The solution to "the compiler warns me about type errors" is not "ignore the compiler"... One correct solution is to type the variable correctly, with `let name1?: string`. Another is to write code to ensure the variable is not undefined.

Comment: I find this operator so funny, its basically telling Typescript "just trust me bro"

Answer (score 270):

I know this is a kinda late, but another way besides [yannick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062363/6603342) to use `!` is to cast it as string thus telling TypeScript: *I am sure this is a string*, thus converting it.

```js
let name1:string = person.name; // Error here compile time
```

to

```js
let name1 = person.name as string; // No error here compile time, runtime though
```

This will make the error go away, but if by any chance this is **not a string** you will get a run-time error... which is one of the reasons we are using TypeScript to ensure that the type matches and avoid such errors at **compile time**.

Comment: This might make the error go away, but it never changes the actual type of the variable.

Comment: I am sorry but i think you are quite mistaken there, as i have mentioned this will in fact change the type as it will throw a runtime exception if the type doesnt happen to be a string or fails to have a toString method. This will cast whatever is there into a string, i.e you have a number it will attempt to call the .toString function of whatever you have there.

Comment: But that won't be the correct way right, say if my name has number "0" in it, it would just covert it to string... Rather it should throw an error and say invalid name. Personally, I would not use this typecast and specially check for the type passed in the object .. but we all have different coding styles, open for more discussion on the same

Comment: Yes but this completely out of the context of the question that this answer was given. We do not know if this is a form if there are no steps to filter that out before hand. Also what you are suggesting there would be impossible at that stage without some really dirty workarounds.

Comment: No need for workarounds, just one check before you try to access the variable. Both cases would be handled easily, errors would go away and your code will be safer. Just try it out :)

Comment: You can use `as string` but the output won't be any different from `person.name!` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCLIN7IA4H4BcyAzmFKAObIC+AUACYQIA2cUKCA9iCcnYagG4aNJhDDI4hEmRCUAvLwB02CUWKkKQ0eIBGUjbOQK6ygIQCgA)). You might get a runtime error, **but it will not happen at assignment** as this post suggests. Both this and the top solutions are bad practices; you should check `name` is defined or use `??`/`||` to coalesce to a default value. Only do this if you know for certain `name` is defined (like in the OP question).

Answer (score 196):

To avoid the compilation error I used

```
let name1:string = person.name || '';
```

And then validate the empty string.

Comment: What if it isn't a string but object?

Comment: If it an object then instead of ' ' it will be {}

Comment: This is something when you can do when you are chaining values and you get this sort of error `Optional chain expressions can return undefined by design - using a non-null assertion is unsafe and wrong.`

Comment: This is not a solution for given problem. The compiler is there to help spotting potential problems whereas an assignment like `person.name || ''` is just a delegation of the problem to somewhere else.

Answer (score 75):

As of TypeScript 3.7 you can use **nullish coalescing operator** `??`. You can think of this feature as a way to “fall back” to a default value when dealing with null or undefined

```js
let name1:string = person.name ?? '';
```

The `??` operator can replace uses of `||` when trying to use a default value and can be used when dealing with booleans, numbers, etc.  where `||` cannot be used.

As of TypeScript 4 you can use `??=` assignment operator as `a ??= b` which is an alternative to `a = a ?? b;`

Answer (score 51):

By your definition `Person.name` can be null but `name1` cannot.
there are two scenarios:

### `Person.name` is never null

tell the compiler your are sure the name is not null by using `!`

```
let name1: string = person.name!;
```

### `Person.name` can be null

specify a default value in case name is null

```
let name1: string = person.name ?? "default name";
```

Comment: Best answer by far here. Precise and offering multiple solutions.

Answer (score 29):

A more production-ready way to handle this is to actually ensure that `name` is present. Assuming this is a minimal example of a larger project that a group of people are involved with, you don't know how `getPerson` will change in the future.

```
if (!person.name) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected error: Missing name");
}

let name1: string = person.name;
```

Alternatively, you can type `name1` as `string | undefined`, and handle cases of `undefined` further down. However, it's typically better to handle unexpected errors earlier on.

You can also let TypeScript infer the type by omitting the explicit type: `let name1 = person.name` This will still prevent `name1` from being reassigned as a number, for example.

Comment: This is the most complete answer, not just a work-around that could lead to issues later down the line. Thank you!

Comment: @dingo thank you! The question asked "how do I get around this error?" but that is not the right mindset.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a quick way to get what is happening:

When you did the following:

name? : string

You were saying to TypeScript it was optional. Nevertheless, when you did:

```
let name1 : string = person.name; //<<<Error here
```

You did not leave it a choice. You needed to have a Union on it reflecting the undefined type:

```
let name1 : string | undefined = person.name; //<<<No error here
```

Using your answer, I was able to sketch out the following which is basically, an Interface, a Class and an Object. I find this approach simpler, never mind if you don't.

```
// Interface
interface iPerson {
    fname? : string,
    age? : number,
    gender? : string,
    occupation? : string,
    get_person?: any
}

// Class Object
class Person implements iPerson {
    fname? : string;
    age? : number;
    gender? : string;
    occupation? : string;
    get_person?: any = function () {
        return this.fname;
    }
}

// Object literal
const person1 : Person = {
    fname : 'Steve',
    age : 8,
    gender : 'Male',
    occupation : 'IT'  
}

const p_name: string | undefined = person1.fname;

// Object instance 
const person2: Person = new Person();
person2.fname = 'Steve';
person2.age = 8;
person2.gender = 'Male';
person2.occupation = 'IT';

// Accessing the object literal (person1) and instance (person2)
console.log('person1 : ', p_name);
console.log('person2 : ', person2.get_person());
```

Answer (score 12):

try to find out what the actual value is beforehand. If `person` has a valid `name`, assign it to `name1`, else assign `undefined`.

```
let name1: string = (person.name) ? person.name : undefined;
```

Comment: hmmm. That will be too verbose if I want to do multiple assignments. Is there a way to turn off this particular warning?

Comment: unfortunately not except you make `name` mandatory by removing the question mark.

Comment: PS: Which version of TypeScript do you use? I use 3.2.4 and do not run into this Message. In my test class the code perectly compiles.

Comment: same version. I get this error in webstorm but not in vscode

Comment: That is strange, because I use IntelliJ which is supposed to be similar to WebStorm when it comes to application of TS-rules?!

Comment: I am sure there must be a way to disable the rule. Otherwise, it will lead to insanity in code.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1: Remove the explicit type definition**

Since `getPerson` already returns a `Person` with a name, we can use the inferred type.

```js
function getPerson(){
  let person = {name:"John"};
  return person;
}

let person = getPerson();
```

If we were to define `person: Person` we would lose a piece of information. We know `getPerson` returns an object with a non-optional property called `name`, but describing it as `Person` would bring the optionality back.

**Solution 2: Use a more precise definition**

```js
type Require<T, K extends keyof T> = T & {
  [P in K]-?: T[P]
};

function getPerson() {
  let person = {name:"John"};
  return person;
}

let person: Require<Person, 'name'> = getPerson();
let name1:string = person.name;
```

**Solution 3: Redesign your interface**

A shape in which all properties are optional is called a *weak type* and usually is an indicator of bad design. If we were to make `name` a required property, your problem goes away.

```js
interface Person {
  name:string,
  age?:string,
  gender?:string,
  occupation?:string,
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this!

```
let name1:string = `${person.name}`;
```

but remember `name1` can be an empty string

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. I'm trying to do `<div style={{color:this.props.color}}>text</div>`. This is so weird.

Comment: This solution is the only one works for me. The other high up answers do not work. So strange.

Answer (score 4):

You trying to set variable `name1`, witch type set as strict string (it MUST be string) with value from object field `name`, witch value type set as optional string (it can be string or undefined, because of question sign). If you really need this behavior, you have to change type of `name1` like this:

```
let name1: string | undefined = person.name;
```

And it'll be ok;

Answer (score 4):

if you want to have nullable property change your interface to this:

```
interface Person {
  name?:string | null,
  age?:string | null,
  gender?:string | null,
  occupation?:string | null,
 }
```

if being undefined is not the case you can remove question marks (?) from in front of the property names.

Comment: Hi, I know its been a while. What if this interface is a parameter to a function. How do i pass the parameter. Would just passing something like this work { } , Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: @vigneshasokan: An interface type cannot be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `NonNullable` Utility Type:

**Example**

```
type T0 = NonNullable<string | number | undefined>;  // string | number
type T1 = NonNullable<string[] | null | undefined>;  // string[]
```

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullablet).

Answer (score 3):

This was the only solution I found to check if an attribute is undefined that does not generate warnings

```
type NotUndefined<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Record<K, Exclude<T[K], undefined>>;
function checkIfKeyIsDefined<T, K extends keyof T>(item: T, key: K): item is NotUndefined<T, K> {
    return typeof item === 'object' && item !== null && typeof item[key] !== 'undefined';
}
```

usage:

```
interface Listing { 
    order?: string
    ...
}
obj = {..., order: 'pizza'} as Listing
if(checkIfKeyIsDefined(item: obj, 'order')) {
    order.toUpperCase() //no undefined warning O.O
}
```

original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60084270/12975352)

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `<Person>` casting from your `getPerson` function, then TypeScript will be smart enough to detect that you return an object which definitely has a `name` property.

So just turn:

```
interface Person {
  name?: string,
  age?: string,
  gender?: string,
  occupation?: string,
}

function getPerson() {
  let person = <Person>{name: 'John'};
  return person;
}

let person: Person = getPerson();
let name1: string = person.name;
```

Into:

```
interface Person {
  name?: string,
  age?: string,
  gender?: string,
  occupation?: string,
}

function getPerson() {
  let person = {name: 'John'};
  return person;
}

let person = getPerson();
let name1: string = person.name;
```

If you cannot do that, then you will have to use the "definite assignment assertion operator" as @yannick1976 suggested:

```
let name1: string = person.name!;
```

Comment: What's the point of having an interface and not using it for typing?

Answer (score 1):

I think to use `Require` as mentioned by Karol Majewski is quite nice. Another way to achieve the same would be to use intersection types(which is actually used internally by `Require`)

```js
function getPerson(): Person & {name: string} {
  const person = {name:"John"};
  return person;
}

const person = getPerson();
const name1: string = person.name;
```

The advantage of using `Require` or intersection types is that we don't overrule the typescript compiler as it happens for the non-null assertion operator.

Answer (score 1):

You could tighten up your types. Your `getPerson` function says it returns a `Person`, which implies that every property in the resulting value may be optional/undefined. But given the context of `getPerson`, we can make a stronger statement: the resulting value certainly has a `name` property! I would refactor `getPerson` to be:

```
function getPerson() {
  return { name: 'John' } as <Person & { name: string }>;
}
```

Now `getPerson().name` will be typed as `string`, not `undefined | string`.

You could go even further, and remove the typing altogether:

```
function getPerson() { return { name: 'John' }; }
```

Typescript will infer the type from the returned value, and again, `getPerson().name` registers as type `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding condition using ternary operator. The purpose of this line is to assign `name1` the value of `person.name` if it is defined, and an empty string if not.

```
interface Person {
  name?: string,
  age?: string,
  gender?: string,
  occupation?: string,
}

function getPerson() {
  let person = <Person>{ name: "John" };
  return person;
}

let person: Person = getPerson();
let name1: string = person.name ? person.name : ''; // Added condition
```

Comment: This approach is already given in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54496418/15261914

Answer (score 0):

One thing that was happening to me in my particular situation (but it is not related with the specific problem asked here) was that I was **importing** the **wrong type** in my file, given that the type was called exactly the same, but defining different properties.

Once I **imported** the **correct type**, all the issues dissapeared.

I hope this can help someone that's facing the same as me.

Answer (score -16):

Had the same issue.

I find out that react-scrips add `"strict": true` to `tsconfig.json`.

After I removed it everything works great.

**Edit**

Need to warn that changing this property means that you:

> not being warned about potential run-time errors anymore.

as been pointed out by [PaulG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141661/paulg) in comments! Thank you :)

Use `"strict": false` only if you fully understand what it affects!

Comment: This may 'work'. But it only works in the sense that you're not being warned about potential run time errors anymore.  I'd encourage research on what the strict checking in Typescript does : https://medium.com/webhint/going-strict-with-typescript-be3f3f7e3295

Comment: I should mention that the OP asked, "How do I get around this error?" not, "How do I fix this issue?"

Comment: Simply adding  name:string = undefined (as recommended by packages like json2typescript) will throw error 2322 unless you turn strict off, which is what most people will need to do.  This accepted answer is clear, correct, and deserves many more votes.