# TypeScript: Tell TypeScript a function checks for `typeof !== undefined`

Tags: typescript

How do I let TypeScript know that a function validates that an item contains a given key?

e.g.:

```
function doesItemHaveKey(item: any, key: string): boolean {
  return typeof item === 'object' && item !== null && typeof item[key] !== 'undefined';
}

interface testInterface {
  optional?: string;
  some: string;
}

let testObj: testInterface = {
  some: 'value'
};

if (doesItemHaveKey(testObj, 'some')) {
  // Do something with testObj.some
  // TypeScript throws errors because `testObj.some` could be undefined
}
```

Things I've tried:

```
if (doesItemHaveKey(testObj, 'some') && typeof testObj.some !== 'undefined') {
  // This works, but duplicates the typeof check
}

function doesItemHaveKey(item: any, key: string): key is keyof item
/**
 * A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
 *  Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
 *    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
 **/
```

Comment: I think you forgot an ? on `some` otherwise `some` is not types as possibly undefined

Comment: Even if it is optional, `testObj.some` doesn't give a type error in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type assertion version will work, you just need to add some generic type parameters to capture the `item` type (in `T`) and the actual type (in `K`). You can then use the type-guard syntax to tell the compiler the `item` parameter is `T` in an intersection where the key `K` is required (which will effectively make the key `K` required)

```
function doesItemHaveKey<T, K extends keyof T>(item: T, key: K): item is T & Required<Pick<T, K>> {
  return typeof item === 'object' && item !== null && typeof item[key] !== 'undefined';
}

interface testInterface {
  optional?: string;
  some?: string;
}

let testObj: testInterface = {
  some: 'value'
};

if (doesItemHaveKey(testObj, 'some')) {
  testObj.some.big() // string 
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgUwM4EkpoLYASAhgG5oDSaAngDwAqANIuYmgB65jIaIDW1cYIjoA+ABQxceAFzCm-KrPIBKWZPyIYPOogBkiAEpoAjiBgAnNMhoAFGBF70m5ESMQBvALAAoRIktQIOZIUFQADmiCmlKIALzxiADkcABGAFZo0Il6+up4iACECWAgADalOYihEVF5ANoKALqFCYngyGjAMGBWiQDcPgC+Pog+3bjmwEQQaFWYUFhgE1MzHiOIcGGwCESlAPyyGFDm3QDmA76IGHB4aAdXx2cXw94+pWhQc0cA8umyuEdFstprNYmtLtdbrJEiRdiA0Ikhhc-GMhGJUJgcPhiGRKFQxACoL80kxEpCEcplOC-ITiQA6cl0lIwU5iKkAenZDxOYFOo28gyAA)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `doesItemHaveKey` a [user-defined type guard](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), using generic type parameters and `Exclude` to construct a subtype of `T` where the key `K`'s value is not `undefined`.

```js
type NotUndefined<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Record<K, Exclude<T[K], undefined>>;

function doesItemHaveKey<T, K extends keyof T>(item: T, key: K): item is NotUndefined<T, K> {
    return typeof item === 'object' && item !== null && typeof item[key] !== 'undefined';
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAqgOwCYQGYEtkVQHgBUAaKAaSggA9gI0BnKAawhDgykID4oBeTqADIoAJQgBjOACcCZUgFEq4gDYBXdEQDaZALqlVaTDjxcuAbgBQFjAfHAscZFFRwI9AJK0AtgAkAhgBuEGSsRKQU1LQMzKzsnFwAFFjeAFycpCwgaWQAlGnJEF5QWIzwSIbYuAQk5DwA3hZQUFIQwKpSTqCQcQVFvP1QAORwAEYAVhLAg0LCvVAAhAPIqsrKM1BdED3empk6CwODBuiVeIOWAL5WOLRSGH7i0IRuwO7It-ePUA1NcGD2jj8ygA-Gl6MApDgAOaWJr0OBeCBgiHQy5WZStDYvADy4zSz3Bbw+D2g-B+UHhiLSgwCQNUEEGFgulgsWA4CRcbk8hX8QRCIAStHBuLGpGG-wcyCBgxyOW+jSxwvGADo-gCpWsAPSaiko5BQ0jIBC6yH6qAAHygxyMVSZQA)

Comment: unlike the accepted answer this one worked for me.