# Typescript: in operator not asserting type

Tags: typescript

I have an object `a` that only contains a subset of the keys defined in type `B`. I then have a variable `d` of type `B`. I want to extract the value for key `d` from `a` in case it exists there.

```
const a = {x: 'c'}
type B = 'x' | 'y'

const example = (d: B) => {
  let e: string
  if (d in a) e = a[d]
}
```

But Typescript will complain with error 7027 on `a[d]`:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'B' can't be used to index type '{ x: string; }'.
>
> Property 'y' does not exist on type '{ x: string; }'

It seems that the compiler is blind to the check `d in a`.

Why? And what’s the best way to solve this?

Comment: Note the limitations of `in` narrowing: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing. `d` isn't a string literal and `a` doesn't have a union type.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but [this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60084103/12299000) should answer the part about what to do instead.

Comment: The `in` operator `key in obj` only narrows the type of `obj`, and only if `key` is of a single string literal type, and only if `obj` is of a union type.  Since your `key` is a union and your `obj` is not, the `in` operator will not do any narrowing.  Even [ms/TS#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732), if implemented, would probably not do what you want, since all that would possibly do is narrow `a` from `{x: string}` to `{x: string} | {y: unknown}`.

Comment: What's the *primary* question, here?  Is it "why is this happening?" Or is it "how do I work around it"?  If it's "why", then I can explain that by expanding on the above.  If it's "how", then it depends on your use case.  The example you posted would be better solved by `if (d === "x")`.  If you have a list of keys then you might want a type guard to narrow `d` to an element in the list like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WoDeaw).  It's technically unsound to assume `(d in a)` implies that `d` is one of the *known* keys of `a`, see [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqEgkm).

Comment: Another approach is [this one](https://tsplay.dev/NBj64N) where you are explicitly defining `a` to be `Partial<Record<...>>` and then instead of using an `in` type guard (which doesn't work how you want) you just read `a[d]` and check it.  Let me know if you want to see any of this written up as an answer.