# error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<User, void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, void>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular.

How can I solve this problem?

I have installed `Angular CLI: 11.0.7` and `Node: 12.18.4`

**Error:**

> Error: src/app/_services/account.service.ts:19:7 - error TS2345:
> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<User, void>' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, void>'.
> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
> Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'User': username, token
>
> ```
>  19       map((response: User) => {
>           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>  20         const user = response;
>     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ...
>  24         }
>     ~~~~~~~~~
>  25       })
>     ~~~~~~~~
> ```

**account.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';


export class AccountService {
  baseUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/api/';
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', model).pipe(
      map((response: User) => {
        const user = response;
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
      })
    )
  }
}
```

**user.ts**

```
export interface User{
    username: string;
    token: string;
}
```

[image: The error]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

you need to cast the http.post return

```
  login(model: any) {
    //-------------- here ⇊⇊ ------
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', model).pipe(
      map((user : User) => {
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: good god, thank you... just set strict on a project i'm working on and could not figure this one out.

Comment: removing strict: true from tsconfig flle resolved this compiler issues, this may not be efficient but works as quick fix if you know exactly what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

http.post can be typecast to User or any

also try

```
login(model: any){
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', model).pipe(
      map((response: User)=>{
        const user = response as User;
        if(user){
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

[Typescript: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496398/typescript-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-string/54496418)

`"strict": true >>>> "strict": false`