# Angular - Type undefined is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use this google dynamic form for Angular 11 as is and I get errors.

Here is all the code copied verbatim, obviously it works here but is giving me errors on my dev machine.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sccsnu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion-base.ts

√ Compiled successfully.

```
Error: src/app/_models/question-base.ts:21:5 - error TS2322: Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | undefined'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'undefined'.

21     this.value = options.value;
       ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: is your tsconfig.json different in dev machine?

Comment: can you try adding `!` to `this.value = options.value!;` please?

Comment: Raz, that fixed it, thanks, if you make this an answer instead of a comment I can mark it correct.

Comment: Great glad it work for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496398/typescript-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-string)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding ! to ‘this.value = options.value!;’ should fix it because ‘!’ operator indicate this value isn’t nullable.

Comment: Hahaha, I love javascript

Comment: @FrankieDrake this is TypeScript, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

You can get rid of all the errors of "Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'"
by setting the property **"strict" in tsconfig.json file to **false****

Comment: Please don’t do that. There’s no reason in using TypeScript if you disable the type checks. It’s like disabling your fire alarm instead of extinguishing a fire.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the type of `options`

```typescript
   options: {
      value?: T;
  }
```

So `options.value` will be of type `T | undefined` because of the `?` that implies value is optional

Now the type of `this.value`

```typescript
  value: T;
```

So `this.value` will be of type `T`

Now lets say we do not provide any value for `options.value` then we will be assigning `this.value = undefined` which should ideally warn us as `this.value` is of type `T`

In short the solution is either to remove the optional parameter `?` or to change the type of `this.value`

```typescript
value: T | undefined
```

Comment: Removing the ? gives me a different error:
`value: T`


Property 'value' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ value: T; key?: string | undefined; label?: string | undefined; required?: boolean | undefined; order?: number | undefined; controlType?: string | undefined; type?: string | undefined; options?: { ...; }[] | undefined; }'.`

Leaving it and adding `T | undefined` gives me the same error as my question:

Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | undefined'.