# Typescript : Type is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, typescript, types, undefined

I'm getting the below error for this TypeScript code :

```
getTollById(id: number): Toll {
  return this.toll
    .filter(toll => toll.id === id)
    .pop();

}
```

Comment: Because your `filter` can return an empty list, in which case `pop` will return `undefined`.

Comment: Another way of putting it, what would you like to return if `filter` returns an empty array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496398/typescript-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-string)

Comment: Try to avoid mutations in TS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DarBen,

The array method, `filter`, returns an array inferred from the instance. This could return an empty array. When using `pop()` on an empty array, you will get `undefined` as seen [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG8BQyywmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz4C+++C6IAzmMmFui7kM2ANoBdZAF5ko3MTLIAjMmYAaPAvIAmVeKYduvftml8BXAHQxgAG0hQAFCZxSAfOeyWS0qTKUAlJYADujBjgEGnFzothCWtugA5s4WkcgA9BnIAKogCAAWcCBJEJjItACeyKHByHBJcKA8yDb20MhcoEitdg7IUBBglFDc9RQQAO71UFBwlezRsfGJKS5WbQ6ppu6e6N7lfjIALEG1EelZuSCYEDYgZUA).

Also, the use of `pop` will not affect the list of TODOs. I'm not sure if you were thinking the todos array would be affected? The first playground link demonstrates that.

If you are just looking to find the todo in the list, you can use the `find` method, which does the same as `filter` followed by `pop`, but IMO shows that you are looking for an item without the ambiguity that the original array might be affected. [Here is a complete example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG8BQyywmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz4C+++CANnAM7dpboAMsG5g8hZAnQhRUSgjDooACgAOUYADc4kZAH1F2buQzYA2gF0AlHmSsJAcwhhT6AEIBPAJKZlJclR00DYERERSMmLUcB70rsgAvMhgABYiAHQGAtzpMKC+hjgJAHzJAukkiQlJJFZMYcQwyMoAhNGxEK4hEg2pUOgA7hQQQwCiUP0qAAYAqiBwtBwoish5IJjIcGXYq0rEGwAkuCTMU3U9dhdQzpRQIMjtcQL1l-ZgUB7iRCAj-NjComUZlw+3IAEY7AAaWz+ZAAJjs1nSThcAk8PmUAFZzsxJDoEClmtAoN1wtJuOgluliUplMScUA).