# Events and functions in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have such code:

```
export class Board {
chessBoard: HTMLCanvasElement;
ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
squareSize: number = 80;
letters: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];
numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
pieces: IPiece[] = [];
newStepsArr: IStep[] = [];
lightCell: string = '#efd9b7';
darkCell: string = '#b48866';
constructor() {
    this.chessBoard = document.getElementById('chessBoard-canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    this.chessBoard.onclick = (e) => this.clickEvent(e);
    this.ctx = this.chessBoard.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
}
clickEvent(e: MouseEvent): void {
  const squareCoords: ClientRect = this.chessBoard.getBoundingClientRect();
  const coordX: number = e.clientX - squareCoords.left;
  const coordY: number = e.clientY - squareCoords.top;
  const clickedColumn: number = Math.trunc(coordX / this.squareSize);
  const clickedRow: number = Math.trunc(coordY / this.squareSize);

  this.newStepsArr && this.newStepsArr.forEach((step: IStep) => this.redrawSquare(step.row, step.column, step.item && step.item.image));
  for (const f of this.pieces) {
      if (f.row === clickedRow && f.column === clickedColumn) {
          f.steps?.forEach((step: IStep) => {
              this.addHighlight(step.row, step.column);
              step.item = this.pieces.find(f => f.row === step.row && f.column === step.column);
          });
          this.newStepsArr = f.steps;
      };
  }
}
```

When I click on my piece i need to add highlite, but now I have such an error in this place
this.newStepsArr - Type 'IStep[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IStep[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IStep[]'.

How to handle it?

And interface

```
export interface IPiece {
id: number,
column: number,
row: number,
color: TColors,
name: TName,
image?: HTMLImageElement,
steps?: IStep[],
make?(row: number, column: number): void,
newSteps?(row: number, column: number): void,
```

}

export interface IStep {
row: number,
column: number,
item?: IPiece,
}

Comment: We'll need to see more code; this seems to be related to the type of `this.pieces` but that's not included in your question.

Comment: @Jacob one moment

Comment: @Jacob added more code, look please

Comment: `newStepsArr` cannot be `undefined` by definition and `f.steps` can. One way to remove the error is to write `this.newStepsArr = f.steps || [];`. This way `this.newsStepsArr` is guranteed to be an array. There are of course more ways but it depends.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496398/typescript-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `IPiece['steps']` is `IStep[] | undefined` because of the optional `?` suffix added to the `steps` property type definition. That is why you cannot assign it to `this.newStepsArr`, which has type `IStep[]`. You'll either want to make `this.newStepsArr` *also* optional or handle the case where `f.steps` is undefined:

```
this.newStepsArr = f.steps ?? []; // Convert undefined to empty array
```