# H88 Error: Invalid account: #0 for network - Expected string, received undefined

Tags: javascript, config, solidity, hardhat

This is my hardhat.config.js -

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: "https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today",
      accounts: [process.env.pk]
    },
    // polygon: {
    //   url: "https://polygon-rpc.com/",
    //   accounts: [process.env.pk]
    // }
  }
};
```

When running npx hardhat test the following error appears:

```
**Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:
   Invalid account: #0 for network: mumbai - Expected string, received undefined**`
```

Seems I have a couple of errors with my hardhat.config.js file but can't locate. I am using Nader Dabit's full-stack-web3 tutorial for full stack web3 development.

Comment: Your `process.env.pk` is undefined. Just make sure its set properly.

Answer (score 11):

Correct:

```
 mumbai: {
  url: "https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today",
  accounts: process.env.pk
```

Incorrect:

```
 mumbai: {
  url: "https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today",
  accounts: [process.env.pk] <-- remove the array
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with how the `accounts` datatype is defined.

`accounts` is of type `HardhatNetworkAccountsUserConfig`. It contains an array of `account` objects, which is of type `HardhatNetworkAccountUserConfig`.

(Notice how `accounts` has 'Accounts' in this type name while `account` has 'Account')

Now, this `account` is an object that contains two values: `private key` and `balance`
. You can read more about it [here](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#accounts).

This is enough background knowledge. Let's jump into the code.

First, define `accounts` as such:

```js
import {HardhatNetworkAccountsUserConfig} from "hardhat/types/config";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const accounts: HardhatNetworkAccountsUserConfig = [
  {
    privateKey: process.env.pk!,
    balance: ethers.utils.parseEther('10000').toString()
  }
]
```

Notice the '!' after `process.env.pk`. The reason for its addition is well explained in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496398/typescript-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-string).

Now, define the `config` using the code below:

```js
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: "https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today",
      accounts
    // polygon: {
    //   url: "https://polygon-rpc.com/",
    //   accounts
    // }
  }
};
```

`npx hardhat node` should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it a different way because it was still saying invalid account (although I was on the goerli testnet). I figured out you need to put a 0x in front of the private key so I added an OR statement to the PRIVATE_KEY variable as follows:

```
const PRIVATE_KEY =
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY ||
    "0xfake1private2key3fake4private5key6fake7private8key"
```

and then used that variable as follows:

```
networks: {
        goerli: {
            url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
        },
```