# How to persuade typescript to accept that array isn't empty?

Tags: typescript

I have simple code construction:

```
const arr: number[] = [1];
while (arr.length > 0) {
   const current: number = arr.pop();
   ...
}
```

Typescript argues (to "const cutrent") that "***Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'***"
Obviously from condition of "while" that the variable "current" is always number (not undefined).
How to explain it to typescript without ugly work arounds?

Comment: if you are sure, just put a `!` behind `arr.pop()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496398/typescript-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const current: number = arr.pop() as number;
```