# Typescript, JSON.parse error: "Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Tags: javascript, typescript, local-storage

The error was happening here:

```
let moonPortfolio;
...
moonPortfolio = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('moonPortfolio'));
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915002/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string) which makes sense, however I'm still getting that error after this refactor:

> As the error says, localStorage.getItem() can return either a string or null. JSON.parse() requires a string, so you should test the result of localStorage.getItem() before you try to use it.

```
if (portfolio.length === 0) {
  const storedPortfolio = localStorage.getItem('moonPortfolio');

  if (typeof storedPortfolio === 'string') {
    moonPortfolio = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('moonPortfolio'));
  }
  else {
    moonPortfolio = [];
  }

  if (moonPortfolio) {
    const savedPortfolio = Object.values(moonPortfolio);
    this.props.fetchAllAssets();
    // this.props.addCoins(savedPortfolio);
  }
}
```

[image]

I first set the results of localStorage `moonPortfolio` to a var, then check if the var is `typeof` string. Yet still getting the typescript error?

Any thoughts or direction here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know too much about the inner workings of `localStorage.getItem` and doesn't make the assumption that the return value will be the same from one call of `getItem` to the next. So it just tells you that it can't be certain that on the second call to `getItem` the result *isn't* `null`.

Try simply passing in the variable you've already created instead of reading from `localStorage` again:

```
if (typeof storedPortfolio === 'string') {
  moonPortfolio = JSON.parse(storedPortfolio);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 10 mins.... also just found out that this also works: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('moonPortfolio') || '{}');`

Comment: @Leon True and that option could be safer if in the *single* edge case of an empty string (`JSON.parse('')` throws a `SyntaxError`), but still I'd prefer explicit type checks and a `try`/`catch` for invalid strings.

Answer (score 44):

Simple fix:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('moonPortfolio') || '{}');
```

Seems like TS does know about the inner workings of localStorage/sessionStorage actually. It returns `null` if you try to fetch a key that isn't set. `null` when treated as `boolean` is falsy so by adding OR the empty stringified json object will be used instead meaning that `JSON.parse(x)` will always be given a string meaning it's then type safe.

Comment: Thank you for such a simple fix!

Comment: Yes this is all I needed lol. I was getting very frustrated by this, unable to get a `string | null` into `JSON.parse` any other way.

Comment: This isn't really the best solution. Instead of `JSON.parse` returning `null`, now it returns `{}`. The better solution is something like:

`const item = localStorage.getItem('moonPortfolio');`
`if (item === null) return null;`
`return JSON.parse(item);`

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript doesn't know that multiple invocations of `localStorage.getItem` with the same string literal will always return the same value (in fact, this isn't even true).

The second call to `localStorage.getItem('moonPortfolio')` may well return `null` - you should call `JSON.parse(storedPortfolio)` instead of calling `getItem` again.

Comment: `null` is a valid value for `JSON.parse` (does not raise an error, returns `null`) - shouldn't the type def for the first argument of `JSON.parse` be `string | null`?

Comment: No, because the very first step of JSON.parse is an implicit coercion of its argument to a string. `JSON.parse(32)` "succeeds" for the same reason but is not allowed either.

Comment: Shouldn't that behavior (implicit or not) be covered by the typings?

Comment: No? You wouldn't want parseInt(true) to not have a type error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750390/what-does-all-legal-javascript-is-legal-typescript-mean

Comment: I'd say that returning `NaN` is different than returning a variable value - still, what you've written in that question seems to act as documentation and clearly outlines what TypeScript does and does not do.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to know is that localStorage.getItem() returns string | null. Knowing that we can re-write the code with a simpler pattern:

```
  const portfolio = []; //Just to make the code samples valid
  if (portfolio.length === 0) {
    let moonPortfolio = []; //Default value
    const storedText = localStorage.getItem('moonPortfolio');
    if (storedText !== null) { //We know it's a string then!
      moonPortfolio = JSON.parse(storedText);
    }
    //The if statement here is not needed as JSON.parse can only return 
    //object | array | null or throw. null is the only falsy value and that 
    //can only happen if storedText is null but we've already disallowed 
    //that.
    //if (moonPortfolio) {
      const savedPortfolio = Object.values(moonPortfolio);
      //Do whatever else is needed...
    //}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

also in react:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data") ?? '{}')
```

or

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data") || '{}')
```