# TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | UrlTree'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

The title of this question is the message what the Angular CLI compiler throws.

I have this constructor in my app.component.ts:

```
    export class AppComponent {
      constructor(private userService: UserService, private auth: AuthService, router: Router) {
       auth.user$.subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
         userService.save(user);

         let returnUrl = localStorage.getItem('returnUrl');
         router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In the above attached code part I have the 'returnURL' underlined and if I take the cursor above it says:

> "Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | UrlTree'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | UrlTree'."

I have a user.service.ts which is related to Firebase:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase';

    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {

        constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  
          save(user: firebase.User) {
          this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).update({
            name: user.displayName,
            email: user.email
         });
       }
     }
```

Does anyone has an idea about what is the compiler's problem here? I also attached the console message.

[image: Console message]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915002/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is giving you all of the information you need.

`localStorage.getItem` returns either a string or `null`, and `router.navigateByUrl` expects a parameter of either a `string` or a `UrlTree`. You'll have to check the return value of localStorage.getItem to make sure it's not null before calling `router.navigateByUrl` because you can't call it with `null`.

```
let returnUrl = localStorage.getItem('returnUrl');
if (returnUrl) { // i.e, not null and not empty string 
    // now returnUrl cannot be null, so it must be a string, which is valid to use in this call
    router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Seams to be it is working and compile error passed away but... the console message still remains the same. I checked the status and I am logged in my Firebase profile so I do not really know what does this "Can't determine Firebase Database URL." means here. Maybe the app can not reach the database somehow.

Answer (score 12):

You have the line

```
let returnUrl = localStorage.getItem('returnUrl');
```

The `getItem()` function returns a `null | string`. If the item is not in the storage, the funtion returns null.

`router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);` expects `returnUrl` to be of type `string | UrlTree` but `returnUrl` is infered as  `null | string` from its initialization hence the error

There are various ways you can resolve this, a simple one would be to typecast the returned value to a string

```
let returnUrl = localStorage.getItem('returnUrl') as string;
```

Comment: Downvote because casting the return value of `getItem` to a string removes the type safety. He'd get an error when invoking `navigateByUrl` when `localStorage.getItem` returns null.

Comment: @xdumaine Downvoting is a choice which I totally am okay with. Downvoting a better solution is also a choice so feel free.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the exclamation mark to tell compiler that the value cannot be null, like this:

```
  let returnUrl = localStorage.getItem('returnUrl');
  router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl!);
```

Comment: By the way, it is called the Non-null assertion operator in TypeScript. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator