# ERROR Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

I have a solution to my previous question at this link:

[TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | UrlTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406954/ts2345-argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type)

Thanks to **xdumaine** I modified the code by his specified lines and the compilation error passed away, but the console errors are still available after compilation:

[image]

Could you please help me about that? Maybe the app does not reach the Firebase database but I checked, I am logged in. Or do I need to specify somewhere in the code that I need to connect to the related Firebase database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `databaseURL` property in your Firebase Config ? Please share a screenshot and blur the credentials.

Comment: Maybe that is my main problem. This example what I attached in the previous question is based on about a 4-years-ago-made code, so I think it has been changed that how to implement Firebase database connection in an Angular app. How can I create this Firebase Config to relate my application? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please share your code where you are initializing Firebase ?

Comment: I don't have an initialization section in the code.

Comment: There must be a part where you enter your Firebase Web Credentials somewhere

Comment: Definitely, and it worked! I initialized firebaseConfig in my app.module.ts, I added the line 'AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)', to the "imports" section, and finally my app worked again, still having one console error which was about  "TypeError: Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new'"  which I resolved by opening tsconfig.json and changed the "target" field from 'es2015 ' to 'es5'. Ran 'ng serve' and voilá: the expected Firebase database object was created! Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To utilize Firebase within your app, you must initiate an instance with your project credentials. The Firebase documentation has several implementations all found [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize).

The credentials for your project should be found [HERE](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) and be in this structure:

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY",
  authDomain: "PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "PROJECT_ID.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID",
  appId: "APP_ID"
};
```

Once initialized, you can access the project's database and other services if you provide the respective credentials seen above as many are optional.