# Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

Tags: angular, typescript

Error: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

Line of error: this.setSession(res.body._id, res.headers.get('x-access-token'), res.headers.get('x-refresh-token'));

````
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private webService: WebRequestService, private router: Router) { }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.webService.login(email, password).pipe(
      shareReplay(),
      tap((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        // auth tokens will be in the header of this response 
        this.setSession(res.body._id, res.headers.get('x-access-token'), res.headers.get('x-refresh-token'));
        console.log('logged in');
        console.log(res);
      })
    )
  }

  logout() {
    this.removeSession();
  }

  private setSession(userId: string, accessToken: string, refreshToken: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('user-id', userId);
    localStorage.setItem('access-token', accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('refresh-token', refreshToken);
  }

  private removeSession() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user-id');
    localStorage.removeItem('access-token');
    localStorage.removeItem('refresh-token');
  }
}```
````

Comment: Have you looked at any of [the other 426 questions about this error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ts+2345+is%3Aq)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915002/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of the arguments `res.body._id`, `res.headers.get('x-access-token')`, `res.headers.get('x-refresh-token')` has null value and you defined their types as a string.

-Try to console.log(res.body._id, res.headers.get('x-access-token'), res.headers.get('x-refresh-token')) and see which one returns null.

-Try to change declaration of
`private setSession(userId: string, accessToken: string, refreshToken: string)` to `private setSession(userId: string|null, accessToken: string|null, refreshToken: string|null)`

Comment: Alternatively, `private setSession(userId?: string, accessToken?: string, refreshToken?: string)`