# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'. Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an error message:

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[image]

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915002/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string?rq=1) but I didn't understand the answers for my problem.

My code is presented like this:

```
const expectedRole = route.data['expectedRole'];
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    
const { userName, roleId } = decode(token);
console.log(roleId);
```

[image]

**Edit 2022-02-02**

[image]

decode method

```
export class InvalidTokenError extends Error {}

export interface JwtDecodeOptions {
  header?: boolean;
}

export interface JwtHeader {
  type?: string;
  alg?: string;
}

export interface JwtPayload {
  iss?: string;
  sub?: string;
  aud?: string[] | string;
  exp?: number;
  nbf?: number;
  iat?: number;
  jti?: string;
}

export default function jwtDecode<T = unknown>(
  token: string,
  options?: JwtDecodeOptions
): T;
```

FYI, I copied the code from the project [here](https://github.com/StilDavila/Angular-Auth-JWT/blob/master/src/app/guards/role.guard.ts)

Comment: Can you specify what did you not understand? I can then explain accordingly

Comment: @Phalgun: Sorry, I don't understand how to solve this problem, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915002/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the typescript compiler telling you that `token` may be `null`. So you need to check that it isn't before using it in the `decode` function, since `decode` does not accept a `null` parameter.

```js
const expectedRole = route.data['expectedRole'];
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

if (token) const { userName, roleId } = decode(token);
console.log(roleId);
```

You can also force the typescript compiler to ignore this using `!`, which says "this variable will be truthy, trust me", but you need to be absolutely sure it will never be `null`, or you may get a runtime error.

```js
const expectedRole = route.data['expectedRole'];
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    
const { userName, roleId } = decode(token!);
console.log(roleId);
```

**Edit**

This solution should work regardless, but you should define the correct return types for decode

```js
const expectedRole = route.data['expectedRole'];
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

if (token) const info: { userName, roleId } = decode(token);
console.log(info.roleId);
```

OR

```js
const expectedRole = route.data['expectedRole'];
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

if (token) const info: any = decode(token);
console.log(info.roleId);
```

**Edit 2**

Looks like `decode` is a generic function, so you can define the return type like this:

```js
const expectedRole = route.data['expectedRole'];
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

if (token) const { userName, roleId } = decode<{ userName, roleId }>(token);
console.log(roleId);
```

Comment: Thank you, I took the first solution. I just have a little problem with `if (token) const { userName, roleId } = decode(token);`, I have an error message `Property 'roleId' does not exist on type 'unknown'` and `Property 'userName' does not exist on type 'unknown'` I don't understand why it keeps bugging?

Comment: What is the return type of `decode`?

Comment: I edited my first post, I put a screenshot at the end of the post with the error, (thanks)

Comment: Show me the decode function please

Comment: I edited my first post again, thanks again for your help.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the exclamation mark is discouraged, and `token as string` should be used instead

Comment: @Chris Hamilton: Thank you Chris, I don't have the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the problem by modifying this:

```
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    public router: Router
  ){ }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot):boolean{
    const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

const { userName, roleId } = decode(token);
console.log(roleId);

if( !this.authService.isAuth() || roleId !== expectedRole){
  console.log('Usuario no autorizado para la vista');
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
  return false;
}
return true;
  }  
}
```

To this:

```
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    public router: Router
  ) { }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const expectedRole = route.data['expectedRole'];
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (!this.authService.isAuth()) {

      console.log('Usuario no autorizado para la vista');
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    };
    const info: { userName: string, roleId: string } = decode(token);
    if (info.roleId != expectedRole) {
      console.log('Usuario no autorizado para la vista');
      this.router.navigate(['login']);

      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

I separated the `if` into two `if`s, each one performing an independent activity.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking like typescript thinks, you need to define a type (i.e. "string", "number", "void") for variables as well as functions or methods.

Ones you have defined type for variables (or for methods), typescript check if its type match with its definition.

In your case `token` is probably **null** and typescript alert you that **string** not match with **null** and rise an error.

So you need to debug token and check if:

- is not null nor undefined
- is a string

In some cases you need to declare type of variable in the following way:

`token: string = ...`