# TS: How can I eliminate the error/warning: Type 'null' is not assignable to type `string`

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I avoid this error "*Type 'null' is not assignable to type `string`.*"?

I checked it in the line above that is not null.

I don't like to disable the null check in general, because it can be very useful. ("strictNullChecks":false) (and it is also not working)

[image]

```js
  catId: string = '';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('feedbackId')) {
      this.catId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('feedbackId');
    }
  }
```

I also tried this to check for null-objects (using question-marks here and there):

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('feedbackId')) {
      this.catId = this?.route?.snapshot?.paramMap?.get('feedbackId')?;
    }
  }
```

Comment: At least closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915002/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string

Comment: How about ``this.catId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('feedbackId') ?? ''`` ?

Comment: If you're convinced that the string will be null you can declare the variable as `catId: string|null = ''`

Comment: I did an answer going through a lot of your options, but that was a bit silly because the answers to previous questions cover all this ground (although a bit scattered). At some point I'll adapt the answer to fit in with the linked original, but in the meantime here's the version I wrote specifically in relation to your code: https://pastebin.com/YnGux1yM I hope that's helpful. :-)