# how to Solve this 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

//I doing This Online Shopping i got stuck with this login service

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  login = true;
  attemptsLeft = 3;
  userID!:number;
  isAdmin:boolean = false;
  isLoggedIn:boolean = false;
  constructor(public _service:UserService, public userSer:UserService, public route: Router, public empSer: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
```

/* **Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'**

```
this.userID = JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem("userId")));//problem here 

    if(this.userID.toString() != ""){
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
    let employee = this.empSer.getEmployee(this.userID).subscribe(employee =>{
      this.isAdmin = employee[0].isAdmin;
    });
    //if user -> send to user
    if(this.isLoggedIn){
      this.route.navigate(['/home-page']);
    }
  }
  checkLogin(loginRef:any){
    this._service.attemptLogin(loginRef).
    subscribe((id: string)=>{
      console.log(id);
      if(id == ""){
        console.log("incorrect");
        this.login = false;
```

**problem here Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'**

```
    let incorrectAttempts = 
 JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("incorrectAttempts"));
        console.log(incorrectAttempts);
        if(incorrectAttempts == null){
          incorrectAttempts = 0;
        }
        incorrectAttempts++;
        this.attemptsLeft --;

        if(incorrectAttempts > 2){
          this.userSer.lockUser(loginRef);
        }
```

**problem here Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'**

```
    sessionStorage.setItem("incorrectAttempts", `JSON.stringify(incorrectAttempts));`
      }
      else{
        localStorage.setItem("userId",JSON.stringify(id));
        sessionStorage.setItem("incorrectAttempts","0");
        this.route.navigate(['/']);
      }
    },(error: any)=>console.log(error));
    
  }
}
//user Controller  this is backend service for login 
let login = (req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.emailId;
    let password = req.body.password;
    UserModel.findOne({emailId:email},(err,user) => {
        console.log("looking for user");
        try{
            if(user.password != password){
                res.send(null);
                return;
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        try{
            res.send(user._id.toString());
            return;
        }catch(err){}
    })

    EmployeeModel.findOne({email:email},(err,employee) => {
        console.log("looking for employee");
        console.log(employee);
        try{
            if(employee.password != password){
                res.send(null);
                return;
            }
        }catch(err){
            return;
        }
        res.send(employee._id.toString());
    })
}
//server.js login 
baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/user"
attemptLogin(loginRef:any):any{
  return this._http.post(`${this.baseURL}/login`,loginRef,{responseType:"text"})
}
please help me ! Pictures [This is the Error Picture][1]
```

Comment: JSON.parse requires a string. getItem could return null. TypeScript is doing exactly what it's supposed to - what _do_ you want to happen in that case? You need to deal with that possibility for your code to compile.

Comment: Well, `sessionStorage.getItem()` can return `null`. `JSON.parse()` won't like that.

Comment: Maybe you can check first if it's null then just do the `JSON.parse()` if it isn't. Something like this: `!sessionStorage.getItem("incorrectAttempts") ? sessionStorage.getItem("incorrectAttempts") : ''` - Sorry if the syntax is incorrect cause I'm not sure lol but that's the idea

Comment: For things with reasonable defaults, nullish coalescing can be handy for this. For instance, `let incorrectAttempts: number = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("incorrectAttempts") ?? "0");` For things without reasonable defaults, just get the `string | null` from `getItem` then check for `null` before parsing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915002/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't necessarily returning anything from localStorage.getItem("userId") that can be JSON parsed.

If userID is just a string, which it seems to be, you can just return it without JSON.parsing it first

```js
this.userID = localStorage.getItem("userId"));//problem here 
this.isLoggedIn = this.userID != "";
```

if you are storing userID as an object, which is implied by how you are stringfifying it in your example, then you might not have set anything to parse

in which case you can do the following.

```js
let idString: string = localStorage.getItem("userId");
this.userID = idString ? JSON.parse(idString) : null; //problem was here
this.loggIn = this.userID != null;
```

You seem to be encountering the same issue in the other examples, but you can fix them the same way, except for this one

```js
sessionStorage.setItem("incorrectAttempts", `JSON.stringify(incorrectAttempts));`
```

which should be

```js
 sessionStorage.setItem("incorrectAttempts", JSON.stringify(incorrectAttempts));
```

Comment: In the last one, you should only be stringifying the answer if it wasn't already a string, and if it is a number, which is seems to be from your code, you can just set it directly, which ```sessionStorage.setItem('incorrectAttempts', incorrectAttempts);``` but you still have to JSON.parse it to get it back.