# angular theating object as a string

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/angularya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=89&codigo=89&inicio=80. and it has the following part of code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  conversion!: string;
  potenciaNumero!: number;
  cantidad!: number;

  formularioConversion = new FormGroup({
    numerodecimal: new FormControl(''),
    base: new FormControl('octal'),
    potencia: new FormControl('2'),
    largo: new FormControl(true)
  });

  submit() {
    if (this.formularioConversion.value.base == "hexadecimal")
      this.conversion = parseInt(this.formularioConversion.value.numerodecimal).toString(16);
    if (this.formularioConversion.value.base == "octal")
      this.conversion = parseInt(this.formularioConversion.value.numerodecimal).toString(8);
    this.potenciaNumero = Math.pow(parseInt(this.formularioConversion.value.numerodecimal?), parseInt(this.formularioConversion.value.potencia));
    if (this.formularioConversion.value.largo)
      this.cantidad = this.formularioConversion.value.numerodecimal.length;
  }
}
```

the problem is that in the submit function i have the variable "numerodecimal" that is defined as an object but threated as a string. How can i solve this error?

[image]

Comment: Because  `numerodecimal` is the property of the `this.formularioConversion.value`  object. Try to type cast ` parseInt(this.formularioConversion.value.numerodecimal as string)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915002/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use typecasting to get over this.
Here's some options in order of preference

`parseInt(this.formulatrioConversion.value.numerodecimal || "")`

`parseInt(this.formulatrioConversion.value.numerodecimal as string)`

`parseInt(this.formulatrioConversion.value.numerodecimal as any)`